# German equivalent of idiom "Be a catch"

Tags: idiom, phrase-request

How do you express in German that someone is being worth a try for dating, e.g. like in:

> I am taking Laura out tonight. She's such a catch, I hope she likes me.

I am not asking for this sentence to get translated, I want to know the German version to express that someone is worth being with (dating) if any.

Comment: This seems to be either a simple translation request (*Sie ist ein guter Fang.*) Or a bit broad as there are rather a few expressions for this (just as in English).

Comment: This is a idiom, i am not expecting necessarily cath to get literarilly translated

Comment: Was hast Du bisher mit einem Wörterbuch herausgefunden?

Comment: @Robert Sie hat einen Haken/
er ist ein Fang from direct translation but how do i know it is correct

Comment: I corrected some minor spelling mistakes, but I don't understand the structure of the first sentense: "How do you express that in German, of someone being worth e.g.:"

Comment: @Iris I try to say that someone is worth a try for dating

Comment: @WeaponX, OK, I reformulated the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers seem to avoid the elephant in the room for some reason:

The common German version of that expression would be ***Sie ist ein guter Fang*** or ***Sie ist eine gute Partie***.

While I agree that idioms are notoriously hard to translate, most of them would still make some sense in other languages. *She has a hook* or *She is a catch(snag/hitch)* would not make sense.

Comment: `Fang` would usually mean she's conquered, whereas in the question the case is still developing.

Comment: "Erfolgreich gefangen/eingefangen" ist eine Frau erst mit einem Ring am Finger ;)

Comment: Eine "gute Partie" hat eine stärkere Betonung auf der finanziellen Seite.

Answer (score 0):

Ich kenne keine direkte Übersetzung für das englische "is a good catch". Im Deutschen würde ich es umschreiben mit "sie ist eine tolle Frau" oder genauer sagen, was ich an ihr toll finde "sie sieht super aus und hat einen tollen Humor".

In keinem Fall kann man es mit "sie hat einen Haken" übersetzen; wenn etwas im Deutschen einen Haken hat, ist das im Englischen "where is the catch?", i.e., you are looking for the (hidden) disadvantage.

Comment: Aye, there’s the rub …

Answer (score 0):

> She's such a catch

could be "germanized" to:

> Sie ist ein Klasseweib / Sie ist eine Klassefrau

or to:

> Sie ist ein Superweib

Comment: *Weib* klingt archaisch oder abwertend. In der umgekehrten Reihenfolge …